# Should my service layer methods completely encapsulate a unit of work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm thinking about refactoring some C# code of mine, in which I've implemented the repository pattern with Entity Framework 6. It's an ASP.NET MVC4 website. Currently, I've got a service layer on top of my repositories. The service layer holds my business logic, such as get all users where X is greater than Y, etc.

A similar project of mine, with the same implementation is here: https://github.com/ryancole/BetterArmory

Right now, a client of my library would use my library like so (without DI for brevity):

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var userRepository = new MyUserRepository(context);
    var userService = new MyUserService(userRepository);

    var user = userService.getById(1);

    user.Name = "Foo Bar";

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Above, `MyDbContext` is my class that inherits from EF6's DbContext. My `MyUserRepository` repository class, and all other repos, take the context as an arg. Further more, the service classes take the appropriate repository class as an arg.

So, the things I'm thinking about refactoring somehow are the leakiness of this implementation, I feel like. The classes returned from my service layer are EF6 proxies, in most cases, and can be modified directly with the `SaveChanges` method, on the `DbContext`, saving those changes. This is difficult for me to perform validation on, because I'm using Fluent Validation which EF doesn't seem to really have any knowledge of. As far as I know, I have to manually call `Validate`, from Fluent Val, in my service layer methods. This is bad because those direct changes to the proxies objects aren't performed through a service layer method. Even if I had a service layer method called `SetUserEmail` or something, in which I validated the entity with Fluent Val, the user could still directly edit the proxy properties.

So I was wondering, is it perhaps better to make my service layer initialize the `DbContext`, the repository and perform the changes, calling any needed Fluent Val stuff, etc, all in a single function?

Some down sides to this, off the top of my head, may be that lazy loading would have to be explicit in the service methods or just disabled all together and load everything. That's all I can think of at the moment, but I know I had other downsides I thought of earlier.

Answer (score 1):

For me it makes sense to encapsulate UoW (in this case that is DbContext) into the service layer. A service is a transactional behavior and can span one or more database operations into that one transaction, where if one operation failed the entire service should fail.

Normally, the application layer should not know about the DbContext and its repositories. It should delegate all logic operations to the service layer. In the case of MVC this will result to a skinny controller, whose sole responsibility is to decide the proper routing/re-routing based on the result of the service call.

It is okay to have lazy loading in the service layer, loading everything will lead to grave performance issues.

I have built an online scaffolding tool that demonstrates this kind of architecture. If you are interested you can check it out at [Camote Q](http://camoteq.com).

Comment: That's cool. The site doesn't like my library that contains my `DbContext`, though. It says it can't find it. Do you have some example code that the site generates?

Comment: @Ryan, currently it will work only with MVC4 and EF5.  Send me an email at mfcguru@yahoo.com and I will be happy to send you a working sample.